# Angular/Ngrx store error: Cannot read property 'whitelist' of undefined at isFiltered

Tags: angular, ngrx

I work on Angular project, where I use @ngrx/store-devtools and Chrome Redux DevTools extension. Today noticed, that somehow in console appeared this error: Cannot read property 'whitelist' of undefined. I didn't change nothing, so it's very weird. Also after disabling Redux DevTools extension, error fixes.

Comment: please elaborate your R&D part!

Comment: Thera are a OFFICIAL workaround to fix for now the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53514787/4231054